# What's the right way to count the thread run time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, runtime

Like this:

```
    thread t1(getPrimes,begin,end, ref(vect));
    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    t1.join();
    finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Or like this:

```
    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    thread t1(getPrimes,begin,end, ref(vect));
    t1.join();
    finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Should I start it before or after thread t1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beginning of a new execution thread is sequenced ***only*** with the completion of `std::thread`'s constructor.

In the first version, the entire execution thread ***could*** theoretically run and ***finish*** before the original execution thread calls `now`() for the *first* time. C++ gives you no guarantees whatsoever that the execution thread won't actually start and run only after the first call to `now`.

The second version is guaranteed to cover the entire execution thread, plus a little bit of overhead of `std::thread`'s construction.

Even better would be to move the run time capture into the actual execution thread itself.